# get synchronized terminal output to java variable

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, terminal

I have this code to execute terminal command using java and storing output in string variable but sometimes the output changed. How to get continuous output into a file or string?

When I execute command I get initial output for first output
but in this example when a client connected to access point the output change saying someone connected how to get this output to a variable?

```
//String output : stores the output of airbase-ng  but after a while the     
//output will change because it will notify me when something happened < so 
//how to store the output again

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 class ExecuteShellComand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

        String domainName = "google.com";

        //in mac oxs
        String command = "airbase-ng start mon0";

        String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

        System.out.println(output);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output);

    }

 String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                        String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It was not very clear for me.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. For me, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve and what your exact problem(s) is/are.